# Cannot find the declaration of element 'OFX'

Tags: java, xsd, xml-validation

I have already checked the similar questions but none of them are solving my problem.
I am validating my xml string with the OFX schema.
Here is the schema
[OFX.xsd](http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/ee6b9c7cac6b)

And my xml string is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OFX>
<SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
    <SONRS>
        <STATUS>
            <CODE>0</CODE>
            <SEVERITY>INFO</SEVERITY>
        </STATUS>
        <DTSERVER>20120716233626.570[-7:PDT]</DTSERVER>
        <LANGUAGE>ENG</LANGUAGE>
        <FI>
            <ORG>Symitar</ORG>
            <FID>01182</FID>
        </FI>
        <INTU.BID>01182</INTU.BID>
        <INTU.USERID>66983</INTU.USERID>
    </SONRS>
</SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
<BANKMSGSRSV1>
    <STMTTRNRS>
        <TRNUID>0</TRNUID>
        <STATUS>
            <CODE>0</CODE>
            <SEVERITY>INFO</SEVERITY>
        </STATUS>
        <STMTRS>
            <CURDEF>USD</CURDEF>
            <BANKACCTFROM>
                <BANKID>
                </BANKID>
                <ACCTID>66983-S80</ACCTID>
                <ACCTTYPE>CHECKING</ACCTTYPE>
            </BANKACCTFROM>
            <BANKTRANLIST>
                <DTSTART>20120501</DTSTART>
                <DTEND>20120716</DTEND>
                <STMTTRN>
                    <TRNTYPE>FEE</TRNTYPE>
                    <DTPOSTED>20120713135400</DTPOSTED>
                    <TRNAMT>-25.00</TRNAMT>
                    <FITID>30403620120713WF</FITID>
                    <NAME>Account Transaction</NAME>
                    <MEMO>Withdrawal Fee</MEMO>
                </STMTTRN>
              </BANKTRANLIST>
            <LEDGERBAL>
                <BALAMT>-254.64</BALAMT>
                <DTASOF>20120716233626</DTASOF>
            </LEDGERBAL>
            <AVAILBAL>
                <BALAMT>-254.64</BALAMT>
                <DTASOF>20120716233626</DTASOF>
            </AVAILBAL>
        </STMTRS>
    </STMTTRNRS>
</BANKMSGSRSV1>
</OFX>
```

The Java code i am using to validate the xml is

```
InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("OFX.xsd");
        Source ofxsource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(output));
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
            .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new StreamSource(in));
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        try {
          validator.validate(ofxsource);
          System.out.println("Source is valid");
        } catch (SAXException e) {
          System.out.println("Source is NOT valid");
          System.out.println("Reason: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("IOException "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
```

I am not getting any error but it is not validating the xml and the message i am getting is "Cannot find the declaration of element 'OFX'".
If anyone solved this issue regarding OFX validation then kindly share the solution.

Comment: Your XSD is invalid , you will need to have elements not just complex types, `<xs:element name="OFX">...<xs:complexType>....   </xs:element>  `

Comment: Yeah i think this was the problem and i have changed it, but now i am getting this error, "Invalid content was found starting with element 'SEVERITY'. No child element is expected at this point". However in xml i don't have any child element for <SEVERITY>

Comment: You do not have a `SEVERITY` node in the XSD on the `STATUS` complex type however its is on your XML

Comment: SEVERITY is there on STATUS

 <xs:complexType name="STATUS">
  <xs:choice>
   <xs:element name="CODE" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"
    maxOccurs="1" />
   <xs:element name="SEVERITY" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"
    maxOccurs="1" />
   <xs:element name="MESSAGE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"
    maxOccurs="1" />
  </xs:choice>

Comment: @Kenneth, Please let me know what do you mean by not having SEVERITY node in xsd on the STATUS complex type

Comment: Your XSD does not match the XML you are trying to validate. Why do you have a choice when it seems its not one or the other element, further on this you should change the xsd to use `ref="myelement"` then `<xs:element name='myelement'><xs:complexType.......`

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined a root element in the OLX.xsd

Modify the `<xs:complexType name="OLX" >` to be `<xs:complexType>` and wrap it with an element tag

```
<xs:element name="OFX">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="SIGNONMSGSRQV1" type="SIGNONMSGSRQV1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="SIGNONMSGSRSV1" type="SIGNONMSGSRSV1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="SIGNUPMSGSRQV1" type="SIGNUPMSGSRQV1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="SIGNUPMSGSRSV1" type="SIGNUPMSGSRSV1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="BANKMSGSRQV1" type="BANKMSGSRQV1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="BANKMSGSRSV1" type="BANKMSGSRSV1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="CREDITCARDMSGSRQV1" type="CREDITCARDMSGSRQV1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="CREDITCARDMSGSRSV1" type="CREDITCARDMSGSRSV1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="LOANMSGSRQV1" type="LOANMSGSRQV1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="LOANMSGSRSV1" type="LOANMSGSRSV1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="INVSTMTMSGSRQV1" type="INVSTMTMSGSRQV1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="INVSTMTMSGSRSV1" type="INVSTMTMSGSRSV1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="SECLISTMSGSRSV1" type="SECLISTMSGSRSV1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```